# Android - How can i set Counter for more than one notification in Android with only one icon?

Tags: android

I have been posted my code here please give me a solution for set notification counter with single icon on notification bar insted of more than one notification.

```
this.getApplicationContext();
mManager = (NotificationManager) this
        .getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(
        this.getApplicationContext(),
        Activity_Mentor.class);

// @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Notification notification = new Notification(
        R.drawable.dpu_ic_launcher,
        "New Message",
        System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.number=notificationCount++;

intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent
        .getActivity(
                this.getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(
        this.getApplicationContext(),
        getStaffName, chatMessage,
        pendingNotificationIntent);
int NOTIFY_ME_ID = Integer.parseInt(chatId);
mManager.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notification);
```

this is my code which has been used in my application but it did not work for set notification counter with single icon please help me solve thatr problem.

Answer (score 1):

Different notifications are created because of the different `NOTIFY_ME_ID` passed to `mManager.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notification)`.

There can be only 1 notification displayed with 1 id ... meaning that if you pass different ids you'll get different notifications. On the other hand if you call `.notify()` with the same `NOTIFY_ME_ID` the old notification will just be updated (read replaced) with the new one.

Lastly I suggest you use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to build your notifications instead of the plain `Notification` class - that way you'll have better compatibility - both with older versions and also with Wearables.